# Execute 2 observables sequentially and get the result at once - RxJava 2

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this function:

```
public static class CombinedResult<T, R> {
    T t;
    R r;

    public CombinedResult(T t, R r) {
        this.t = t;
        this.r = r;
    }

    public T getObject1() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setObject1(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public R getObject2() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setObject2(R r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

}

public static <A, B> Observable<CombinedResult<A, B>> combineObservablesParallel(Observable<A>
    return Observable.zip(observable1, observable2, new BiFunction<A, B, CombinedResult<A, B>>() {
        @Override
        public CombinedResult<A, B> apply(A a, B b) throws Exception {
            return new CombinedResult<>(a,b);
        }
    });
}
```

It combine **2** observables and return **1** Observable, which will get the result of both observables into `CombinedResult` object, The problem here is **`zip`** function combine the observables on Paralllel.

I want something same as `zip` that executes the observable sequentially and return the result in `BiFunction` or something like this.

what can be the solution ?

Comment: Try `Observable.concat()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap` operator on `observable1` combined with `observable2` and `zip` operator:

RxJava 1:

```
return observable1
                .flatMap(new Func1<A, Observable<CombinedResult<A, B>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<CombinedResult<A, B>> call(A a) {
                        return Observable.just(a).zipWith(observable2, new Func2<A, B, CombinedResult<A, B>>() {
                            @Override
                            public CombinedResult<A, B> call(A a, B b) {
                                return new CombinedResult<>(a, b);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

RxJava 2:

```
return observable1.flatMap(new Function<A, ObservableSource<CombinedResult<A,B>>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableSource<CombinedResult<A,B>> apply(A a) throws Exception {
        return Observable.just(a).zipWith(observable2, new BiFunction<A, B, CombinedResult<A, B>>() {
            @Override
            public CombinedResult<A, B> apply(A a, B b) throws Exception {
                return new CombinedResult<>(a,b);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

RxJava 2 Lambda:

```
return observable1.flatMap(a -> Observable.just(a).zipWith(observable2, CombinedResult::new));
```

Comment: Thank you, I just modified the code abit for RxJava 2